# How to convert from String to List/Array .?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, list

I have 3 strings
a=38 186 298 345 0.93345
27 198 277 389 0.86006
33 127 293 354 0.89782

Type(a)

len(a) shows it as 22 including splace between 2 numbers

Want to convert them to list
Need as below
b=[[38 186 298 345 0.93345][27 198 277 389 0.86006][33 127 293 354 0.89782]]

Comment: Neither your input (`a`) nor your output (`b`) are valid python. It's unclear what the result you want to get is. Right now, it looks like you're asking for a SyntaxError. Also, what have you tried to transform `a` into `b`? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you aim for:

```
a = '''38 186 298 345 0.93345
27 198 277 389 0.86006
33 127 293 354 0.89782'''

b = [line.split() for line in a.split('\n')]

b

#[['38', '186', '298', '345', '0.93345'],
# ['27', '198', '277', '389', '0.86006'],
# ['33', '127', '293', '354', '0.89782']]
```

Comment: I tried this.. It gives an error " list object has no attribute split

Comment: @AjItHHeGdE That could only be if your variable `a` is a list. Is it? Declared as above it sure works.

Answer (score 0):

Split them by newline and spaces. Use this python function.

```
string_name.split(str="")
```

For more info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution specific to your data.

Note your inputs are not valid Python, I have resolved that below.

```
a1 = '38 186 298 345 0.93345'
a2 = '27 198 277 389 0.86006'
a3 = '33 127 293 354 0.89782'

res = [[float(j) if float(j) < 1 else int(j) for j in i.split()] \
       for i in [a1, a2, a3]]

# [[38, 186, 298, 345, 0.93345],
#  [27, 198, 277, 389, 0.86006],
#  [33, 127, 293, 354, 0.89782]]
```